# SQL Server Agent Job is not running

Tags: sql, sql-server-agent, sql-job

I have a job that is supposed to run every 11 AM and 8 PM. About two weeks ago, it started to not respect the schedule. The "fix" that I found was to start the job manually and then the job would restart respecting the schedule for a while but eventually the issue reappears.

The big problem is that there are no error message what so ever. If the job fails, I am supposed to get a notification Email which I do not. In the sql server agent logs and the Job history, there are no errors. In the job history, I can see clearly that the job skipped the schedule since there are no entries. It looks like it did not even start as if the running time had not arrived.

The schedule is set to run everyday and there are no limits on how long it is supposed to run. The sql Agent is set to restart automatically if it stops unexpectedly.

Did anyone get this problem before?

Comment: I've seen the SQL agent fail like this if there is a domain and the DC holding the "primary domain controller" role is inaccessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the user which is used to run the job. Maybe the user password is expired or the user itself is no longer active.

Comment: It is working under my account now. I had that problem with an account but the jop was notifying me of teh error. I deleted and remade all teh steps, we'll see how that works